# how to convert json object which is starting with digit to c#?

Tags: c#, deserialization, asp.net-core-webapi

how to convert json object which is starting with digit to c#?

My model is :

```
    public class TransactionPaymentResponse
    {
         [JsonPropertyName("3DSecure")]
        public _3DSecure _3DSecure { get; set; }

       // removed rest
    }

    public class _3DSecure
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Deserializtion

```
 var responseStream = await httpResponseMessageForTranscation.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            responseTranscation = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionPaymentResponse>(responseStream);
return responseTranscation;
```

This is my json string(outcome of http post request)

```
"{\"statusCode\":\"2001\",\"statusDetail\":\"Transaction rejected.\",\"transactionId\":\"3D941962-A0FE-37ED-503A-BBEE4C6EE535\",\"transactionType\":\"Payment\",\"retrievalReference\":0,\"paymentMethod\":{\"card\":{\"cardType\":\"Visa\",\"lastFourDigits\":\"0006\",\"expiryDate\":\"0223\",\"cardIdentifier\":\"2DEDC06B-6F96-4C78-8E64-9F1CD2107A8F\",\"reusable\":false}},\"amount\":{\"totalAmount\":50,\"saleAmount\":50,\"surchargeAmount\":0},\"currency\":\"GBP\",\"fiRecipient\":{},\"status\":\"Rejected\",\"avsCvcCheck\":{\"status\":\"NoMatches\",\"address\":\"NotProvided\",\"postalCode\":\"NotProvided\",\"securityCode\":\"NotProvided\"},\"3DSecure\":{\"status\":\"NotAuthenticated\"}}"
```

But The output of responseTranscation is :

```
{
    "statusCode": "2001",
    "statusDetail": "Transaction rejected ",
    "transactionId": "3D941962-A0FE-37ED-503A-BBEE4C6EE535",
    "transactionType": "Payment",
    "retrievalReference": 0,
    "3DSecure": null   
   // reomved rest of the output
   }
```

What is wrong with my model of _3DSecure?

In the jsonString the value is `\"3DSecure\":{\"status\":\"NotAuthenticated\"`
But in my respinse `3DSecure: null`

Why? anyone help me please

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your model, whatever is giving you that "JSON" result is what's wrong, because valid JSON cannot start with anything else than a `{` (the start of a JSON object). If you have control over whatever is producing the JSON change it there to produce valid JSON, if you don't have control over it then you'll need to do some preprocessing (i.e remove the `3DSecure : null` string from the start of your JSON)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JsonPropertyName` attribute is used with the `System.Text.Json` serializer.

For `Newtonsoft.Json`, you need to use the `JsonProperty` attribute.

```
public class TransactionPaymentResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("3DSecure")]
    public _3DSecure _3DSecure { get; set; }

   // removed rest
}

public class _3DSecure
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

With those changes in place, your sample JSON deserializes correctly.